# Monodroid Exception

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Why does the following code give an exception at Line 2?:

```
Stream myInput = this.Assets.Open("test.db");
int l = (int)(myInput.Length);  // <------ Exception
Toast.MakeText(this, l.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

All examples use:

```
InputStream myInput = this.Assets.Open("test.db");
```

for line 1, but I can't find a directive for `InputStream`. Could that be the problem?

Regards...Andrew

Comment: Which Exception? What do you mean "can't find directive for InputStream"?

Comment: The exception is: > 0x13 in Skylog_Pro.ActivityMain.copyDataBase at E:\Android Project\Skylog Pro\Skylog Pro\ActivityMain.cs:92 c#. If I use Input Stream, I get the error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'InputStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Android Project\Skylog Pro\Skylog Pro\ActivityMain.cs 90 9 Skylog Pro

Comment: Answered myself in 'Convert Android Code to MonoAndroid Code' at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194263/convert-android-code-to-monoandroid-code